# Updating dynamically linked .so file within .so file and statically linked .a file within .so file

Tags: linux, openssl, shared-libraries, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have a .so file called abc.so
If I type:

```
ldd abc.so
libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f76f9100000)
```

If I type:

```
ls -l /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.1e
```

Why is it linking to libssl.so.10 instead of libssl.so ? When I update openssl rpm I notice that:

```
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
```

still exists, but is there ever a case that updating an rpm would use something like libssl.so.11 in which case the dynamically linked file used in abc.so would be out of date?

Also, if I have def.so which contains:

```
/usr/lib/libssl.a(libssl64.so.0.9.8)
```

Since that is statically linked, does that mean that no matter what version of libssl.a is there since it was statically linked it will always use libssl64.so.0.9.8 ?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it linking to libssl.so.10 instead of libssl.so ?

On linux, multiple DSOs of the same name are allowed, so you could have (as you say) `libssl.so.11` and/or  `libssl.so.9` installed along with `libssl.so.10`.  All `ldd` is telling you is that `abc.so` is linked to `libssl.so.10`.  A change in these version numbers usually indicate a *backward incompatibility*, instead of a simple bugfix.

> is there ever a case that updating an rpm would use something like libssl.so.11 in which case the dynamically linked file used in abc.so would be out of date?

It *is possible*, because again, multiple libraries are allowed.  However, I would hope that the distro maintainer would *never* introduce a backward incompatible library in an update.

> Also, if I have def.so which contains:
>   /usr/lib/libssl.a(libssl64.so.0.9.8)

I don't know what you've got there.  Looks like it references a shared library to me.